# What happens after round 7?

Tags: teamfight-tactics

If we see here, there is 7 rounds mapped for TFT https://lolchess.gg/guide/rounds

But if there's still 2 players alive after 7 rounds, what does the game do?

Comment: So far every game I played/watched ended within stage 7. Could be that you can never get past stage 7

Comment: It would be very rare. Latest i've seen a game go is Early round 7.

Comment: The link in my other answer also lists Mech monsters. My guess woud be that the game goes on and there are other monsters (those Mechs or Rift / Elder Dragon whichever hasn't appeared previously). Not sure though and with the game still having patches I think most sources are outdated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From what I gathered from Reddit, it seems that if the game continues after Round 7, it just repeats the setup of Round 7. 3 rounds, caroussel, 2 rounds, Elder or Herald.

The game is bound to end at some point, since units are forced onto the board and there is no way that no damage might be done in a round.

Next question would be, how high can you realistically take it?